# Is there a way to make an array of a user-defined class type in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a java class `Jist`that has two fields, `public final Object type` and `public Object[] content`. In the constructor for `Jist` I want to take in an `Object` and get its type, then initialize `content` with some number of empty slots of that type. This is one of the several solutions that I have tried, and the error that I am currently receiving is in the actual initialization of the array:

```
public class Jist{
public final Object type;
public Object[] content;
public Jist(Object type){
    this.type = type.getClass();
        class myType extends Jist{
            Class c = super.type.getClass();
            public Class getType(){
                return c;
            }
        };
    content = new myType.getType()[4];
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you actually need an array of that type? For example, `ArrayList<E>` doesn't contain an `E[]`, it just has an `Object[]`, and the compiler checks the type of things put into it.

Comment: Although that would work fine, during this quarantine I wanted to challenge myself lol. The thing that stumped me was using reflection -- I hadn't heard of it until today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Jist` generic on some type `T`. Pass the `Class<T>` in the constructor. Use [`Array.newInstance(Class<?>, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-) like

```
public class Jist<T> {
    public final Class<T> type;
    public T[] content;

    public Jist(Class<T> cls) {
        this.type = cls;
        content = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, 4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create new array instance using type Class.

```java
Class<?> myTypeClass = myType.getType();
int arraySize = 10;
Object array = Array.newInstance(myTypeClass, arraySize);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayInstance.html